# Hibernate - map one pojo to another pojo one poroperty

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have two entities

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "person")
Class Person {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private String id ;
private String addressId;
private String name ; 
// gets etc...}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
 Class Address {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")      
  String id ; 
  String personId ; 
  String streetId ; 
  String country ;
 // gets etc... }
```

let's assume for my need that address  have lots of persons and each person has only one address
I would like to add to Person 
**the property country alone**
 how can i achive it ?

in the end I would like to have one pojo

```
@Entity
 @Table(name = "person")
class PersonWithCountry{
    @Id
@Column(name = "id")
private String id ;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name ; 
@Column(name = "what to write here")
private String country ;
```

//get set
}

}

Comment: A relationship between objects involves putting the Address object in Person (as per all JPA guides). Clarify what part of that you don't like

Comment: @yoav.str Please elaborate on what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JPA` annotations:

In your `Person` class

```
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Address.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Address address;
```

In your `Address` class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "address")
private List<Person> persons;
```

Comment: does not anwser the question.